# Link that preselect dropdown option with jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a select with options that have values that are populated with jQuery based on data attributes from divs.
 When a user select an option, the div with the data attribute that matches the value of the option is displayed.
 Now I'm trying to create a deep linking option, so when I have a url like https://my-site.com/page/#option-2 the option-2 is preselected in the select and the div with data attribute option-2 is displayed.
 So far I have this javascript:

```
$(window).on('load', function() {
  let urlHash = window.location.hash.replace('#','');
  console.log(urlHash);

  if ( urlHash ) {
    $('.dropdown').val(urlHash);
    $('body').find('.location').removeClass('is-active');
    $('body').find(`.location[data-location-hash=${urlHash}]`).addClass('is-active');
  }
});
```

If I enter the url https://my-site.com/page/#option-2 the site goes in infinite loop and never loads without displaying any error in the console.. 
If I refresh the page while loading, the console.log is displayed with the correct string that I'm expecting, but the .location[data-location-hash=option-2] is not displayed and the option is not selected... 
I'm using the same code for the change function of the dropdown and is working, but it's not working in the load function.. Is there anything I'm missing?

JSFiddle, if it's of any help:
https://jsfiddle.net/tsvetkokrastev/b0epz1mL/4/

Answer (score 0):

Your site is looping because you are doing a `window.location.replace`
 To get the `urlHash` you should use

```
$(window).on('load', function() {
  var href = location.href; // get the url
  var split = href.split("#"); // split the string
  let urlHash = split[1]; // get the value after the hash

  if ( urlHash ) {
    $('.dropdown').val(urlHash);
    $('body').find('.location').removeClass('is-active');
    $('body').find('.location[data-location-hash='+urlHash+']').addClass('is-active');
  }
});
```

https://codepen.io/darkinfore/pen/MWXWEvM?editors=1111#europe

Comment: I changed it as per your suggestion, but the end result is still the same..

Comment: @tsvetko.krastev what is the end result that doesnt work?

Comment: it still doesn't show the correct div and doesn't select the option.. But the console.log is working.. It goes into an infinite loading and I have to refresh the page in order to load and display the console.log.. Not sure how to paste it here for testing. Here is a jsfiddle of what I have => https://jsfiddle.net/tsvetkokrastev/b0epz1mL/4/

Comment: Try my updated code

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by using a function instead of `$(window).on('load')`.. Also added `$( window ).on( 'hashchange', function( ) {});` to assure that the js will run again after the hash is changed.
Here is an updated jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tsvetkokrastev/b0epz1mL/5/